# I need help decorating this plot

Tags: plotting, labeling

I need to combine these plots of `fdk` (in blue) and `RiemannXi` (in orange) into one plot with all 3 pairs of axes in a form that allows labeling. I haven't been able to figure this out.

**Edit---something to make this more interesting---** We can put `Zeta[s]` in as the third plot and legend. We get a crossover at {0,-1/2}. Awesome connections!

So grab one of the plots below and check it out.
**Edit2---new plot w/o legends**[image: new plot]

Note: we constructed a unit-square within the 3 plots that connects them together.

```
fdk[s_] := 1/2 - 1/(2 s + 1)
{Plot[{fdk[s], \[Pi]^(-s/2) (-1 + s) Gamma[1 + s/2] Zeta[s]}, {s, -10,
    10}, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {1/2, 1/2}, Frame -> True], 
 Plot[{fdk[s], \[Pi]^(-s/2) (-1 + s) Gamma[1 + s/2] Zeta[s]}, {s, -10,
    10}, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True], 
 Plot[{fdk[s], \[Pi]^(-s/2) (-1 + s) Gamma[1 + s/2] Zeta[s]}, {s, -10,
    10}, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {-1/2, -1/2}, Frame -> True]}
```

[image: Left Plot]
[image: Center Plot]
[image: Right Plot]

Comment: You simply need to write "Show@" in front of your expression: {Plot....}

Comment: In v10.0 and later, [`RiemannXi`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RiemannXi.html) is built-in.

Comment: @DanielHuber, `Show` doesn't combine the axes, so I need a way to make them lines.

Comment: @BobHanlon, the built-in function set the baseline which I didn't want.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by baseline. With v12.1.1, `RiemannXi[s]` evaluates to the expression that you are using and produces identical plots.

Comment: @BobHanlon, oops! the baseline is shown on Alpha, which I had assumed would happen in Mathemantica.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

fdk[s_] := 1/2 - 1/(2 s + 1)
```

To overlay the plots,

```
Plot[{fdk[s], RiemannXi[s]}, {s, -10, 10},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 Axes -> False,
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends -> {fdk, RiemannXi},
 Epilog -> ({Opacity[0.3, ColorData[97][2 # + 4]],
      Tooltip[Line[{{-10, #}, {10, #}}], #],
      Tooltip[Line[{{#, -1.25}, {#, 3}}], #]} & /@ (Range[-1, 1]/2))]
```

[image]

However, this clutters up the plot. You can use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to select the origin location.

**EDIT:** Added `Zeta[s]` and used independent controls for `x` and `y` origins.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{fdk[s], RiemannXi[s], Zeta[s]}, {s, -10, 10},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  AxesOrigin -> {originx, originy},
  Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> {fdk, RiemannXi, Zeta}],
 Row[{Control@{{originx, 0, Style["x origin", 14, Bold]}, {-1/2, 0, 
      1/2}},
   Spacer[20],
   Control@{{originy, 0, Style["y origin", 14, Bold]}, {-1/2, 0, 
      1/2}}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't figured out how to shift the verticals one spot to the right: 0,1/2,1, without changing the horizontals. Also, as mentioned in the edits, I want `Zeta` inserted as the third plot. If you could change this post so I could grab the new code and the image, I'll throw a bounty your way.

Answer (score 7):

This looks like a job for [`GridLines`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLines.html):

```
gridlines = {#, #} & @
 Thread[{{-1/2, 0, 1/2}, Directive[Thin, ColorData[97]@#] & /@ Range[3]}];

Plot[{fdk[s], RiemannXi[s]}, {s, -10, 10}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 GridLines -> gridlines]
```

[image]

Interactively position and add/remove (`ALT + Click`) grid lines using [`LocatorPane`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocatorPane.html):

```
plot = Plot[{fdk[s], RiemannXi[s]}, {s, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
   ImageSize -> Large];

DynamicModule[{pts = {#, #} & /@ {-1/2, 0, 1/2}}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],
  Dynamic @ Show[plot, 
    GridLines -> (Thread[{#, Directive[Thin, #] & /@ 
           ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length @ pts]}] & /@ Transpose[pts]), 
    ImagePadding -> 30, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, pts[[All, 2]]}, {Automatic, pts[[All, 1]]}}], 
  Appearance -> None, LocatorAutoCreate -> {1, 5}]]
```

[image]